# Using different HTML encodings depending on context for IHtmlString

Tags: asp.net, html-encode, html, ihtmlstring

If you look at anti-XSS libraries they typically have different encodings for HTML content and HTML attributes. For instance using [Microsoft's WPL implementation](http://wpl.codeplex.com/):

```html
<@ Imports Namespace="Microsoft.Security.Application" %>

<span attribute="<%= AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(attrVariable) %>">
    <%= AntiXss.HtmlEncode(contentVariable) %>
</span>
```

Now ASP.Net has added encode bee-stings that make this easier:

```html
<span attribute="<%: attrVariable %>">
    <%: contentVariable %>
</span>
```

You can then [specify the encoder to use in the web.config](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx):

```html
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime encoderType="AntiXssEncoder, AssemblyName"/>
```

The encoder here knows whether to call `HtmlAttributeEncode` or `HtmlEncode` depending on the context.

My problem is that I have a smart class that implements `IHtmlString` - this tells the `<%:` syntax to bypass it entirely. However I still want to encode differently based on context:

```html
<% var item = GetImplementationOfIHtmlString() %>

<span attribute="<%: item %>"> <!-- attribute encodes -->
    <%: item %>                <!-- HTML encodes -->
</span>
```

Is there any way for `IHtmlString.ToHtmlString` to be aware of the context (encoding for HTML content or inside an attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The contract for custom HtmlEncode methods is that they must also be suitable for attribute encoding (when the attribute value is surrounded by quotes).  This way the <%: %> syntax doesn't need contextual awareness.

Comment: But the `<%: %>` has context awareness - if it didn't `HtmlAttributeEncode` couldn't be called. The view renderer knows whether to call `HtmlEncode` or `HtmlAttributeEncode` depending on context when the content is a string, so it should be possible to extend it to create 'smart' self-encoding objects.

Comment: <%: %> always calls HtmlEncode on its input (unless the input is an IHtmlString).  This is hardcoded behavior and cannot be changed.  The syntax is not smart enough to detect whether it is inside an attribute or not.

Comment: Yes, it is. Try adding this class: `public class TestHttpEncoder : HttpEncoder { protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, TextWriter output) { output.Write("[attr]"); base.HtmlAttributeEncode(value, output); } }` and then add `<httpRuntime encoderType="TestHttpEncoder"/>` to the web.config. View the site - any `<%:` in an HTML attribute will have the prefix `"[attr]"`, but any others will not. `HtmlAttributeEncode` will always get called if the `<%:` is in an HTML attribute, so it _must_ be smart enough to detect its context.

Comment: I just tried your snippet, and on my machine the regular HtmlEncode routine gets called, not HtmlAttributeEncode.  If you're seeing HtmlAttributeEncode get called, this is a bug, but we would need a self-contained repro application to diagnose it.  My original point stands: <%: %> isn't intended to be context-aware; it is intended to map to HtmlEncode always.

Comment: Odd, I tested that snippet too and got `"[attr]"` in attributes and didn't get it everywhere else. I'll keep digging. In the meantime do you have any citations/docs that explicitly state that `<%:` are _intended_ to be context unaware by the ASP designers?

Comment: I am a member of the ASP.NET team.  We did not intend to make the <%: %> syntax context-aware.  I do not see anything in our code base that would suggest that this is context-aware.  Use this comment as your citation. :)

Comment: Further digging and I've found my mistake - most of the ASP helpers do call `TagBuilder.MergeAttribute`, and that does call `HttpEncoder.HtmlAttributeEncode`. `<%:` does not, you're quite right. Frustrating though, as while using `<%:` or `@` syntax is definitely best practice, for high-XSS risk sites you really want to use different encoding.